# sails.js get environment value from config in view

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

I use [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) with default template engine ([EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)).
I have a view defined directly from routes config:

**config/routes.js**

```
'/': {
    view: 'homepage'
 }
```

Is there a way to access environment in homepage.ejs?
I need something like this:

**views/homepage.ejs**(next does not work, so I need a working solution)

```
...
<span>Hello you are on <%= sails.env %> environment</span>
...
```

to be rendered as:

```
Hello you are on production environment
```

Please do not suggest me to create controller for this.

I hope there is the way to get it either directly from view or through a locals in route, but how, that is the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
<%= sails.config.environment %>
```